# awk script to match value in one of the csv column in a tab-delimited file

Tags: awk, vlookup

I have tab-delimited file and one of the column($10) is separated by commas if more than one value exists.

I have a list of IDs that I want to match with the above file and find which ID is present. I need code that acknowledges the tab separation and comma separation to find the ID and report "ID_present" in the last column delimited by tab

File1

```
KK2        62652   63579   m64204e     -       polypeptide     61932   64190   A_KK2_000063400 orthologous_to=KK2_0006707300.1     
KK2        62652   63579   m64204e     -       polypeptide     61932   64190   A_KK2_000063400 orthologous_to=KK2_0006707310.1,RR2_000678900.1    
KK2        62652   63579   m64204e     -       polypeptide     61932   64190   A_KK2_000063400 orthologous_to=KK2_0006707310.1,RR2_000678900.1,RR2_000567908.1    
KK2        62652   63579   m64204e     -       polypeptide     61932   64190   A_KK2_000063400 orthologous_to=KK2_0006707310.1,KK2_0007890345.1
```

File 2

```
KK2_0006707310.1
KK2_0006707300.1
```

Outfile

```
KK2        62652   63579   m64204e     -       polypeptide     61932   64190   A_KK2_000063400 orthologous_to=KK2_0006707300.1     ID_Present
KK2        62652   63579   m64204e     -       polypeptide     61932   64190   A_KK2_000063400 orthologous_to=KK2_0006707310.1,RR2_000678900.1    ID_present
KK2        62652   63579   m64204e     -       polypeptide     61932   64190   A_KK2_000063400 orthologous_to=KK2_0006707310.1,RR2_000678900.1,RR2_000567908.1    ID_present
```

`Awk_Script`

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t,"} {OFS="\t"} NR==FNR {a[$10]=$1 ; b[$10]=$2; c[$10]=$3; d[$1]=$n; next} {if ($1 in a) {print $0, "ID_present} else {print $0, "#N/A"} }' file2 file1 > outfile
```

Comment: why isn't the 4th input line also in the output ... since it also contains `KK2_0006707310.1` in the 10th field?

Comment: in the sample provided the string of interest always comes right after the `=`, will this always be the case or do we need to compare all values that come after the `=`?

Comment: will the first 9 fields always be identical for all input lines?

Comment: Think about what `FS="\t,"` means. It's also not clear how you hoped that `{print $0, "ID_present} else {print $0, "#N/A"}` would produce the expected output you show even after fixing the missing `"`.

Comment: It would be a lot simpler if you boild down the example input and output to contain only fields of interest, and with examples that people can overview. Example: Instead of `KK2_0006707310.1` use simple `ABC1` or similar.  Also make sample input that clearly indicate desired match or no match (as "comment").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you're trying to do, assuming the expected output in your question is wrong:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    tgts[$1]
    next
}
{
    stat = "N/A"
    split($10,vals,/[=,]/)
    for ( i=2; i in vals; i++ ) {
        val = vals[i]
        if ( val in tgts ) {
            stat = "ID_present"
            break
        }
    }
    print $0, stat
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
KK2     62652   63579   m64204e -       polypeptide     61932   64190   A_KK2_000063400 orthologous_to=KK2_0006707300.1 ID_present
KK2     62652   63579   m64204e -       polypeptide     61932   64190   A_KK2_000063400 orthologous_to=KK2_0006707310.1,RR2_000678900.1 ID_present
KK2     62652   63579   m64204e -       polypeptide     61932   64190   A_KK2_000063400 orthologous_to=KK2_0006707310.1,RR2_000678900.1,RR2_000567908.1 ID_present
KK2     62652   63579   m64204e -       polypeptide     61932   64190   A_KK2_000063400 orthologous_to=KK2_0006707310.1,KK2_0007890345.1        ID_present
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly. Although, may I know why you initialized with 2 instead of 1?

Comment: @nivitian the 10th field has a format of `x=a,b,c`; the `split()` function is based on dual delimiters of `=` and `,`; the 1st element of the array is going to be the left side of the `=` (`x` in my example) and since you're only interested in the values on the right of the `=` the `for` loop starts with the 2nd position in the array